# What magic does ngModel use that modifying the scope directly does not?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Learning angularjs at the moment, and I am confused as to how I can accomplish a task because I don't fully understand what ngModel is doing.

If I have a directive with two scope variables:

```
// An array of all my objects 
$scope.allMyObjects

// The currently selected object from the array
$scope.selectedObject
```

and in the html

```
<span>{{ selectedObject.name }}</span>

<select id="select"
  ng-model="selectedObject"
  ng-options="object in allMyObjects">
</select>
```

This all works perfectly, when I select an object from the select, it updates the `selectedObject` on the scope and so the name of the currently selected object is displayed.

However, I don't want a select box, instead I want a list of all my objects with an editable name field, with a select button that I can use to select the specified object, so I came up with the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in allMyObjects">
  <input class="object-name"
    ng-model="object.name">
    <a ng-click="loadObject(object)">Load</a>
</div>
```

and the `loadObject()` function on the scope:

```
function loadObject(object) {
  $scope.selectedObject = object;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I had assumed this was basically what ngModel was doing behind the scenes but am obviously confused. Is anyone able to shed some light or offer a better solution to what I wish to achieve?

Comment: Can you show a complete sample? The way it looks now is `loadObject` is not defined as a property of `$scope` and thus leading nowhere when the `ng-click` directive tries to execute the `loadObject(object)` string. Is this your issue?

Comment: Sorry about that, no I don't believe it is. The issue is I'm using typescript and so it's hard for me to convert into normal js full examples, I do have $scope.loadObject = loadObject elsewhere, and console.log() inside the function show it's getting called.

Comment: I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7270/) which does what youre looking for I think, if you can try to upload a complete sample somewhere

Comment: Thanks Philipp, the issue is that both your example and @sylwester both are using a controller (maybe that's the way to go about this, I don't know) whereas I'm currently working on a directive and the HTML I'm writing is in the html template for the directive.

Comment: I see no reason why what I've done shouldn't work however as it's identical to what you have in every other sense.

Comment: Unless you show your full code, I don't know either - the sample posted and what you're trying to do should work from a directive perfectly fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57987/discussion-between-philipp-and-pete-tinkler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of debugging it came down to an issue with the scope being isolated by the ng-repeat, the problem didn't show up in any of the simplified jsfiddle examples because they used pure JS and it was the way I was accessing the scope via typescript that caused the issue.

Thanks for the answers that helped me narrow it down to my difficulty understanding typescript and not my difficulty understanding directives.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here :http://jsbin.com/jocane/1/edit?html,js,output

use  ng-model="object.name" instead "sc.name"

```
<div ng-repeat="object in allMyObjects">
  <input class="object-name"
    ng-model="object.name">
    <a ng-click="loadObject(object)">Load</a>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, this was a typo from copy and pasting